Why Isn't My sphinx-apidoc --templatedir Option Working as Expected?
I am trying to customize ./docs/conf.py to make documentation management easier, so I executed the following command:
sphinx-apidoc -F -o "./docs" --templatedir=./templates "."

I placed the following conf.py_t file in the ./templates directory, but the --templatedir option does not seem to work as expected. (I checked the generated ./docs/conf.py file, and it is different from the template file in ./templates/conf.py_t. Of course, I delete the ./docs directory each time before I execute this command).
Could you please help me understand how to solve this problem?
Thank you for your cooperation.
Here's the details of the problem.
Thank you for your assistance.

OS: Windows

Shell: PowerShell

Python Environment:

Miniconda: 24.1.2
Python: 3.12.2


Sphinx Version: 8.1.3

executed result


ファイル C:\Users\username\Downloads\test\docs\conf.py を作成しています。
ファイル C:\Users\username\Downloads\test\docs\index.rst を作成しています。
ファイル C:\Users\username\Downloads\test\docs\Makefile を作成しています。
ファイル C:\Users\username\Downloads\test\docs\make.bat を作成しています。

this says, each file is generated without an error message. (language setting is Japanese)

conf.py_t File Content
#hogehoge
#hogehoge
#hogehoge
#hogehoge
#hogehoge
#hogehoge
#hogehoge
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
# 
# This file only contains a selection of the most common options. For a full
# list see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = '{{ project_name }}'
copyright = '{{ copyright_year }}, {{ author }}'
author = '{{ author }}'

# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
release = '{{ version }}'

# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode'
]

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = []

# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']


Generated ./docs/conf.py File Content
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# For the full list of built-in configuration values, see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#project-information

project = 'test'
copyright = '2024, Author'
author = 'Author'

# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#general-configuration

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
]

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']

language = 'en'

# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output

html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']

# -- Options for todo extension ----------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/todo.html#configuration

todo_include_todos = True

Note: The generated conf.py file is different from the conf.py_t template file, and I do not know why the template is not being applied.

Just double checking: Can you generate conf.py with templates? I have not seen this myself ever, but I could be wrong. Usually templates refer to HTML and Jinja templates, not the configuration file itself.

This looks like a strange way to use sphinx-apidoc, whose purpose is to generate .rst files to be processed by autodoc. It is not intended to generate conf.py from a template. Maybe the template is indeed applied, but the result gets overwritten since the -F option generates a complete new project.

Thank you both of your comments!After considering your comment and reviewing the Sphinx documentation on HTML Themes Templating, I realized that I was using the --templatedir option incorrectly.
The --templatedir option is indeed intended for customizing HTML output and Jinja templates, not for modifying conf.py. It appears that customizing conf.py this way is not the intended use case for Sphinx.
I understand now that I’ll need to explore a different approach to customize conf.py. Thanks again for helping me recognize the issue and guiding me in the right direction!

Looking back at the Sphinx-apidoc documentation, it still feels a bit confusing. In the section that mentions “Following Jinja2 template files are allowed:”, it lists conf.py.jinja, which led me to believe that conf.py could be customized using templates. However, I haven’t quite grasped the exact meaning or how it works yet.

Does it make any difference if you don't use the -F option?

Thank you for your quick reply. In conclusion. In conclusion, without the -F option, contrary to expectations, neither conf.py nor the desired directory structure was created. However, the generated .rst files (excluding index.rst) were consistent with those produced using the -F option.

Does it make any difference if you change the name of your custom template file to conf.py.jinja (instead of conf.py_t)?

Yes, as you reffered, by changing the extension to conf.py.jinja, it was successfully recognized as a template, and I was able to customize the desired conf.py without any issues. The initial settings to add the path and the command options were also correctly applied. It seems that I can customize modules.rst in the same way. Thanks to this, I can now generate documentation automatically using pipelines like GitHub Actions. Thank you

Resolving the Issue by Changing the File Extension from .py to .py.jinja: To resolve the issue, changing the conf.py file extension to conf.py.jinja allowed it to be recognized as a Jinja template. This adjustment enabled the automatic customization of conf.py with the desired modifications and configuration settings without any complications. In my case, the initial setup to include the path and command options was correctly applied as intended.
